# Why are some instances of the same version string in objdump -T enclosed in paranthesis?

Tags: linux, binary, elf

Look at the following output snippet generated by running `objdump -T` on `libc.so.6`:

```
000000000009f8a0 g    DF .text  000000000000001d (GLIBC_2.2.5) aio_write64
0000000000119d00 g    DF .text  0000000000000034  GLIBC_PRIVATE __pread64_nocancel
000000000009aae0 g    DF .text  00000000000003c0  GLIBC_2.34  pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock
0000000000133db0 g    DF .text  0000000000000354  GLIBC_2.2.5 __backtrace_symbols
00000000001184f0  w   DF .text  00000000000006c2  GLIBC_2.23  fts64_read
000000000009aae0 g    DF .text  00000000000003c0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock
```

Row 1 and 4 of the output have the same `GLIBC` version string but one of them is enclosed in parentheses and the other is not. I've observed this difference across the `objdump` output of a lot of other `elf` binaries. Is there any subtle difference between `(GLIBC_2.2.5)` and `GLIBC_2.2.5` in `objdump` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the description of the `-T` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.39/binutils/objdump.html#index-dynamic-symbol-table-entries_002c-printing):

> If the version is the default version to be used when resolving unversioned references to the symbol then it’s displayed as is, otherwise it’s put into parentheses.

So the library provides version 2.2.5 of `aio_write64`, but only for backward-compatibility; there’s another version that’s used by default. Likewise, the default `pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock` verison is 2.34, but 2.2.5 is also provided.